# WSL2 Ubuntu connection attempt failed

Tags: ubuntu, crash, filesystems, wsl-2

I was running a python program that uses multiprocessing pool, and I encountered an error `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device` after some hours of nearly full usage of CPU and RAM (ext4.vhdx is 155GB out of 256GB). I then run `wsl --shutdown` in Powershell. But after that when I open WSL2 again, it promopts, after some seconds, `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.` I rebooted windows and it doesn't help. Repairing it in "Add or remove programs" doesn't help.

How do I recover from the crash?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I launched a guest virtual machine, specify `ext4.vhdx` as a shared file, and run `virt-rescue` from libguestfs on the vhdx. It turns out that the inodes are used up:
[image: df -i]